# Why do I get the error "NameError: name 'kh' is not defined"

Tags: python, string, if-statement, sys

I'm receiving the input data using sys, there are 2 strings `b` and `l`, those will go to an if-statement and will assign a value to `kh` and other variables, but I keep getting an error about `kh`

The input looks like this:

```py
# Data Input

# Latitude
lat = float(sys.argv[1])
# Longitude
lon = float(sys.argv[2])
# Frequency Band
b = str(sys.argv[3])
# Link Type
l = str(sys.argv[4])
# Elevation
hs = float(sys.argv[5])/1000
```

and the if-statement looks like this:

```py
if b == 'C' and l == 'UL':
    f = 6
    kh = 0.0007056
    ah = 1.5900
    kv = 0.0004878
    av = 1.5728
    tao = 45
elif b == 'C' and l == 'DL':
    f = 4
    kh = 0.0001071
    ah = 1.6009
    kv = 0.0002461
    av = 1.2476
    tao = 45

k = (kh + kv + (kh - kv) * pow(cos(radians(lat)), 2) * cos(radians(2 * tao))) / 2
print('k = ', k)
a = (kh * ah + kv * av + (kh * ah - kv * av) * pow(cos(radians(lat)), 2) * cos (radians(2 * tao))) / (2 * k)
print('a = ', a)
```

I expect the values of `k` and `a` to be floats, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pluviobol.py", line 529, in <module>
    k = (kh + kv + (kh - kv) * pow(cos(radians(lat)), 2) * cos(radians(2 * tao))) / 2
NameError: name 'kh' is not defined
```

Why is this occuring and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Most likely, none of your conditions in the `if` statement are being met, which means `kh` (and also f, ah, kv, av & tao) are never created and thus when your scripts arrives to the definition of `k` there's no `kh` to work with

Comment: I'm giving the right parameters when running the script, my command line looks like this: python pluviobol.py -16 -65 C DL 178

Comment: When I use your posted code and your command line, I get the expected output, rather than the error you describe.  Please provide the required [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, you were right the `if` statement was not being met, I used `b` somewhere else in the code. I changed the name in the input section and now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because of a case not covered by your `if` and `elif` statements. If `b` and `l` do not match either of the 2 cases, the variables are never defined or given a value.

You should add a default `else` case to after your `elif` block, with whatever default values you want:

```
else:
    f = 0
    kh = 0
    ah = 0
    kv = 0
    av = 0
    tao = 0
```

However, if you are getting this problem it means you are probably getting unexpected inputs. You can also add some print statements to determine the values of `b` and `l`, and write corresponding cases.